# stencils parent component variable change do not refresh child component

Tags: stenciljs

I am using 1 stencil component  inside other component

I want to validate input box inside my-input component on click of submit button of form which is in my-form component.

how it can be achieved ?

Comment: Is this stencil.js? You probably want to tag it that then rather than the generic 'stencils'. I'm not sure any of the tags you've used point to any specific software or language.

Comment: I'm also not completely clear what's going on. Your components are my-input and my-form, and the my-input is inside the my-form? When you submit the form you want to trigger validation on the my-input? But the problem is that you're changing some state in the my-form, not the my-input, but it's state that my-input is set up to depend on, and that should trigger a refresh of my-input but that isn't happening?

Comment: yes u are correct.refresh of my-input isn't happening